# Unable to load class Exception - wildfly REST

Tags: java, maven, jpa, wildfly

I have created a JPA jar and used the local repository in maven. Created a seperate REST service and deployed it in wildfly. When i test the JPA project seperately it is working fine. When using the REST api i am receiving the following error. Please help me understand why this is happening.

```
19:29:53,908 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-3) UT005023: Exception handling request to /krypter/employee: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:77)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:220)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:175)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:418)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:66)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at com.krypter.dal.DataAccessLayer.getEntityManager(DataAccessLayer.java:10)
    at com.krypter.repository.EmployeeRepository.<init>(EmployeeRepository.java:23)
    at com.krypter.repository.EmployeeRepository.getInstance(EmployeeRepository.java:30)
    at com.krypter.services.EmployeeService.getEmployees(EmployeeService.java:27)
    at com.krypter.services.EmployeeService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getEmployees(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:402)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:217)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:226)
    ... 81 more
```

wildfly installed drivers

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=datasources:installed-drivers-list
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => [
        {
            "driver-name" => "iseries",
            "deployment-name" => undefined,
            "driver-module-name" => "com.iseries",
            "module-slot" => "main",
            "driver-datasource-class-name" => "",
            "driver-xa-datasource-class-name" => "",
            "driver-class-name" => "com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver",
            "driver-major-version" => 11,
            "driver-minor-version" => 3,
            "jdbc-compliant" => true
        },
        {
            "driver-name" => "h2",
            "deployment-name" => undefined,
            "driver-module-name" => "com.h2database.h2",
            "module-slot" => "main",
            "driver-datasource-class-name" => "",
            "driver-xa-datasource-class-name" => "org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource",
            "driver-class-name" => "org.h2.Driver",
            "driver-major-version" => 1,
            "driver-minor-version" => 3,
            "jdbc-compliant" => true
        }
    ]
}
```

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="krypter-jpa">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/KrypterDs</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.krypter.domain.Employee</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hiberante.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: `com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver` seems not to be on your classpath.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch the JPA project has the driver as it is working when i test it seperately. It is when i invoke it through the REST interface it is not working

Comment: did you deploy the driver in wildfly as well?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch i have added the installed drivers that i got from wildfly to the original question.

Comment: Please show your persistence.xml file. I suspect that you're configuring the driver with properties instead of providing a datasource reference.

Comment: It seems weird Hibernate would even know about that class. Do you try to create the `EntityManager` in code or do you maybe have another `persistence.xml` in your deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke `transaction-type="JTA"` declaration in your *persistence.xml* and inject the *`EntityManager`* via `@PersistenceContext` in your *REST* service.

```
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="krypter-jpa"  transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/KrypterDs</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.krypter.domain.Employee</class>
...
..
```

and in your REST service:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "krypter-jpa")
EntityManager em;
```

With  the *transaction-type="JTA*" the container will do *EntityManager* (*PersistenceContext*) creation for you. You can't use the *`EntityManagerFactory`* to get an *EntityManager* but instead the container will supply this *EntityManager* for you.

Answer (score 0):

add dependency :-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jt400</groupId>
    <artifactId>jt400</artifactId>
    <version>9.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Data Source Properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:as400://172.17.16.21;naming=system;libraries=v8spf
spring.datasource.username=MyUsername
spring.datasource.password=MyPassword
```

Comment: The project works fine as an individual entity. Only when i access it through REST api then it is not working.